# Why does a web site with just a single page not have a bounce rate of 100%

Tags: google-analytics

According to the definition of "bounce rate", it indicates the number of users who visit a site but only one page on the site before navigating away from the site.

But if I have a site with just one web page, I would expect the bounce rate to be 100%, yet Google Analytics shows a rate of 87%. How is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related but rather how google analytics works may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In such cases Google analytics target the time out period. This is a bit different from the time on site. The time out period is in most cases (like for example Google Analytics) 30 minutes. When you're inactive for about 30 minutes a visit will count as a new visit instead of a duration of your former visit.

Answer (score 0):

**Bounce rate is a single page view with no more interaction collected at all.**

If an additional event is sent before the user leaves, GA might not count the single visit as a bounce if the event is not specified to be counted as a "non-interaction" event.

*Exemple of a hit preventing bounce:*

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Super video');
```

*How to fix it with the `nonInteraction` option set to `true`:*

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Super video', {
  nonInteraction: true
});
```

More on GA [Non-Interaction Events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068#NonInteractionEvents).